# 3D Red Blood cell figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello every one i have been working on a red blood cell 3D model in mat lab and all i have come up with is a flattened sphere, i would like to make a depression on both sides of the sphere to come up with at-least a realistic red blood cell my code is as below, what should i add to it to make a realistic red blood cell model?

```
a=1;
c=5;
[u,v]= meshgrid(0:10:360);
x=(a-c*cosd(v)).*cosd(u);
y=(a - c*cosd(v)).*sind(u);
z=a*sind(v);
surf(x,y,z)
axis equal;
```

This is the code of what i have tried but still not close to what i expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    rouleaux = 0;
halfplot = 1;
[X,Y,Z]=sphere(200);
figure(gcf);
clf
Z = Z.*(0.1+0.4.*(X.^2+Y.^2).^1);
th=atan2(X,Y);
if halfplot
    %surfl(   X,Y,Z./( (th>(pi/4+0.1)) + (th<(-3+pi/4)).*(th>(-3*pi/4-1)) )   );
     surfl(   X,Y,Z./((th<pi/4+0.1).*(th>-3*pi/4+0.1))    );
else
    surfl(X,Y,Z);
end
if rouleaux
    hold on
    surfl(X+0.1,Y-0.1,Z+0.5);
    surfl(X+0.1,Y+0.1,Z-0.5);
    surfl(X-0.1,Y,Z-1);
    surfl(X,Y-0.15,Z-1.5);
end
shading interp;
axis equal
grid off;
whitebg('k')
set(gcf,'color','k')
axis off
colormap hot
light
caxis([-0 1.25])
view([176 14])
hold off;
```

Comment: Best Answer so  far. Could you please explain how the rouleaux works please

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm still not quite happy about it (looks more like a [red-wax Gouda cheese](https://www.google.com/search?q=red+wax+gouda&safe=off&rlz=1C1LDJZ_enLU518LU518&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ZJUZU9WtA4eQtQathYGYAQ&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAg&biw=1858&bih=952) than a blood cell), but oh well:

[image]

```
%// Parameters:
a = 0.2; %// Z in the middle
b = 0.8; %// Z at the edge
c = 5;   %// diameter of the bloodcell
n = 50;  %// number of pionts to use on the surf

%// This is copied largely from sphere()
theta = pi * (-1:2/n:1);
phi   = pi/2 * (-1:2/n:1).';

cosphi   = cos(phi);     cosphi(1)   = 0;   cosphi(n+1)   = 0;
sintheta = sin(theta);   sintheta(1) = 0;   sintheta(n+1) = 0;

%// (except for this part)
A = bsxfun(@power, [0; pi/4; pi/2; 3*pi/4; pi], 4:-1:0);
b = [0; b; a; b; 0];
C = A\b;
F = @(phi) sign(phi) .* reshape( (bsxfun(@power, mod(phi(:),pi), 4:-1:0))*C, size(phi) );

x = c * cosphi*cos(theta);
y = c * cosphi*sintheta;
z = F(phi) * ones(1,n+1);


%// Now make the awesome plot
surf(x,y,z,abs(z), 'edgecolor', 'none')
axis equal, grid off, axis off

map = [linspace(0.5,1,n).', zeros(n,1), zeros(n,1)];
colormap(map)

set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'OpenGL');
shading interp, material shiny, lighting phong, lightangle(0, 55)
```

Comment: Thanks its okay, though could you please explain your code please from where you have the cosphi  up to F = @(phi) sign(phi) .* reshape( (bsxfun(@power, mod(phi(:),pi), 4:-1:0))*C, size(phi) ); that is fro line 11 to line 18 please a dnt understnad the bsxfun

Comment: @wysla: `bsxfun()` allows you to do operations on arrays that are "mathematically improper" but make a lot of intuitive sense. For instance: if you have an array of vectors in 3D space (N×3) and you want to normalize each of these vectors, you must divide by the individual magnitudes (N×1). Mathematically, you cannot divide N×3 by N×1, so you'd have to replicate (`repmat(magnitudes,1,3)`) and then divide. `bsxfun` removes the necessity for the replication, that's all.

Comment: @wysla: And the definition of `F(φ)`: I wanted to have a "flat" middle and a bulge at the edges, and such a curve kind of looks like a 4th degree polynomial. So it follows from fitting a 4th degree polynomial through some fixed points, and then a bit of "programmatic mess" to get everything out right :) The matrix `A` are the fixed points in φ, raised to powers 4 through 0. The array `b` are the values for `z` I want to have at the corresponding φ, and the `C` are the best-fit coefficients of said polynomial.

Comment: The result looks pretty nice, but the code could use some comments on how you make the shape.